# Cut angle for BBO type I SPDC

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

I am using an old BBO crystal, which is not designed for spontaneous parametric down conversion, to see whether I can generate converted photons of 800nm from 400nm. I used a photon avalanche detector and I observed some signal of 800 but I couldn't observe them directly or by a CCD.

I would like to know which is the cut angle designed for Type I BBO phase matched SPDC to understand why I couldn't observe the ring of SPDC.

Besides, I use a pulse laser rather than a continuous laser. Is this matters?

Regards